# How does entityClass works in AbstractGenericDao?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Following is the code in one of my office of projects ?

```js
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sha.microservicecoursemanagement.model.IModel;

@Transactional
public class AbstractGenericDao<T extends IModel> implements IGenericDao<T> {

     @PersistenceContext
     protected EntityManager em;

     protected Class<T> entityClass =
             (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

     @Override
     public T find(Long id) {
         return em.find(entityClass, id);
     }

     @Override
     public List<T> findAll() {
         try {

             final List<T> resultList =
                     (this.em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM " + this.entityClass.getCanonicalName() + " v").getResultList());
             return resultList;
         }
         catch(final RuntimeException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     public void save(T entity) {
         em.persist(entity);
     }

     @Override
     public T update(T entity) {
         return em.merge(entity);
     }
     
     @Override
     public void delete(final Long id) {
         em.remove(findReference(id));
     }
     
     @Override
     public T findReference(final Long id) {
         return em.getReference(entityClass, id);
     }
     
     @Override
     public Session getSession() {
         return (Session) this.em.getDelegate();
     }

}
```

I have so many questions in that, first see the code below:

In above code:
(1) What is following line mean ?

```
protected Class<T> entityClass =
                (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

What actually we are doing in above code line ? What is 'ParameterizedType' whay we are doing 'getGenericSuperClass(). What is getActualTypeAruments.
Why we are taking [0]th element ?

(2) What 'em.persist' does ?
(3) What 'em.merge'does ?
(4) What is findReferece method doing ?
(5) What is getSession method doing ? What kind of session it returning ?

Please help, I am new to Java !

Comment: nobody knows the answer ??

Comment: Still one has answer ???

Comment: Don't be obnoxious. If someone can help you - they will.

Answer (score 0):

Java keeps generic type information about the superclass, and you can get it via `Class.getGenericSuperclass()`.

Since your `AbstractGenericDao` is meant to be inherited, `this.getClass()` will always return a sub type of `AbstractGenericDao`. Meaning that `this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` will give you the full generic type of `AbstractGenericDao` e.g. something like `AbstractGenericDao<Book>`. Since you know `AbstractGenericDao` is a parameterized type (it has the type parameter `T`) you can cast it to `ParameterizedType` and then get the actual type of `T` e.g. `Book` by calling `getActualTypeArguments()[0]` (as `T` is the first and only parameter). It's basically a trick to get the actual type of the entity in the DAO.

Now, as written, this code is buggy. `AbstractEntityDao` is not abstract, and can be instantiated directly which will break that line, because its generic super class will be `Object`. Further more, if some class doesn't extend `AbstractEntityDao` directly, but through one more class, that line would likely break again as the super class would then be something other than `AbstractEntityDao`.

As for your other 4 questions - `persist` saves (*persists*) an entity to the DB. `merge` updates it in the DB. These are all basic JPA/Hibernate concepts that you'd learn about in 5 minutes of reading any tutorial. So do your own research before asking, and don't ask 5 questions in one post.